# Laravel migration working but not doing anything

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, migration

> laravel 6.20.29
> mysql 14.14
> server Linux (Ubuntu 18.04.3 LTS)

While deploying my code in one of my aws instances, all migrations where executed, but some did nothing in the database without showing any errors (showing success message only), although in other instances and local it all worked, anyone has ever runned into anything like that?

One of the migrations:

```php
class ModifyDispensacoesTable extends Migration
{
    public function up()
    {
        Schema::table('dispensacoes', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->integer('estoque_triagem_id')->unsigned()->nullable()->after('produtos_lote_id');
            $table->integer('estoque_atendimento_id')->unsigned()->nullable()->after('estoque_triagem_id');

            $table->foreign('estoque_triagem_id')->references('id')->on('estoques_triagens');
            $table->foreign('estoque_atendimento_id')->references('id')->on('estoques_atendimentos');
        });
    }

    public function down()
    {
        Schema::table('dispensacoes', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->dropForeign('dispensacoes_estoque_triagem_id_foreign');
            $table->dropColumn('estoque_triagem_id');
            $table->dropForeign('dispensacoes_estoque_atendimento_id_foreign');
            $table->dropColumn('estoque_atendimento_id');
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: At first you say us that you only get success messages, but later in the post I read that there are some error messages "One of the migrations that presented errors:"

Can you please be more clear?

Comment: Sorry about that, I meant that the example was from one of the migrations that were executed but nothing happened with it